# populating a dropdownlist with xml data in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, drop-down-menu, hash

I need to populate a dropdownlist in ruby on rails with the data in an xml document.

The xml document is formatted like so:

```
<Countries>
    <Country>
        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
        <CountryName>United States</CountryName>
    </Country>
    ...
</Countries>
```

I then tried to convert to a hash using this code:

```
<% countries_xml = File.read(".../countries.xml") %>
<% countries = Hash.from_xml(countries_xml) %>
```

And I got a hash like this:

```
{"Countries"=>{"Country"=>[{"CountryCode"=>"US", "CountryName"=>"United States"}, ... ]}}
```

And I'm trying to use this hash to populate the dropdownlist but I think I am stuck. I've tried like this:

```
<% user.select :country, countries["Countries"]["Country"].each %>
```

But this just fills the dropdownlist with hashes because the countries object is a hash of an array of hashes or something like that. I need it so that the CountryNames are in the dropdownlist and the CountryCodes are sent when the user posts the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation for the select form builder method here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select

Essentially you need to do this to build the array of options for the select:

```
countries["Countries"]["Country"].collect { |c| [c['CountryCode'], c['CountryName'] }
```

Also, you'll probably want to take that xml file read and parsing methods out of the view and pop it into the controller, or even into the model as a class method. It'll help to keep your code more maintainable, but that's just my two cents...